# What is a natural deduction proof from ~(A↔B) to ~(A→B)?

Tags: logic, deduction

It feels intuitively correct, but I cannot work out how to prove it. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: It is not intuitively correct; Two predicates not being equivalent does not prohibit one from implying the other.

Answer (score 6):

The following truth table shows that ~(A↔B) → ~(A→B) is not a tautology:

[image]

If A is False and B is True then the antecedent is True but the consequent is False making the conditional False.

Because the truth table does not show a tautology, one should not be able to derive a natural deduction proof of the result.

---

Michael Rieppel. Truth Table Generator. https://mrieppel.net/prog/truthtable.html

Comment: Thanks very much, that makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

You can't derive ~(A→B) from ~(A↔B).

Consider:

A = I'm in Paris.
B = I'm in France.

~(A↔B) is true, because being in Paris is not equivalent to being in France (I could be in France but not in Paris). But ~(A→B) is false, because if I'm in Paris then necessarily I'm in France. So you can't derive ~(A→B) from ~(A↔B).

Comment: Ah, ok perfect - thank you very much.